# The page numbers of an open book totalled $871$. At what pages was the book open?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, word-problem

So far I have $x + (x-1) = 871$. This has led to one page being $435$ and the other, $436$. Is there anything needing alteration, or is this equation workable?

Comment: Looks good to me.

Comment: The one who designed this problem should have looked at a book before choosing values... When you open a book, the odd page is always the one after the even page (if you don't believe me, just open the book closest to you). So the situation described is not actually possible. It reminds me when I had to solve a problem in high school about paving some room, and in the end the tiles had to be 5 meters by 30 cm or something absurd like that...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This equation (the equation you wrote) works.
x+ (x−1) = 871.
However, the equation x + (x + 1) = 871 also works, since these two numbers are also consecutive numbers.

**Edit**: The solution to the second equation yields the *exact same answer.*

Comment: As long as you understand the answer is $x+1$

Answer (score 0):

The layout of the book does not matter. As long as the numbers add up to $871$, then the answer is correct.

Comment: It does matter. When you have a problem, the solution should take into account reality

Comment: It depends on whether the asker was trying to be a smart-ass trying to trip you with a trick question or whether this was supposed to be a straight-up algebra question asked in earnest by someone who may generally not have known about the convention of page layout.  A proper math problem specifies or has its conditions implicit  There are of course odd-ball books and I could of course have a book published with a page 3 right next to page 868.  Or I could rip out several pages.  Solve it algebraically and if you know this obscure convention point it out as a real life discrepency.